# asp datagrid change submissions best practices and options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have created a grid which I am pulling data that pulling information from sql server. The table is on time shifts. I would like to submit changes, add and delete shifts. I'm curious what some of my options for this are. Im also curious what are considered to be the best practices. 
Thanks, Cal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to build or use a "data layer" in witch you can perform basic data operations (load, insert or update...) But, this depend on the technology you will use... (MVC oriented, data entity model, business Object and SQL query,...) then you can bind your grid to this layer and any actions will be handled from its calls.